# C program exits before logging

Tags: c, logging, error-logging

I've run into stuff like this before but usually just when dealing with `stdout`.

```
#define LOG 1

static void logoutput(char *info) {
    FILE *dbg;
    dbg = fopen(LOGFILE, "a+");
    if(dbg != NULL) {
        fprintf(dbg, "Mix%d: %s\n", MIXNUM, info);
        fclose(dbg);
    }
    else printf("Error writing to log file.\n");
    return;
}

if (data[0] != NULL) {
    if(LOG) logoutput("WARNING, something bad happened on port 1!");
    exit(1); //Adding a sleep(1); before this didn't help.
}
```

The problem I'm having is that when `data[x] != NULL`, the program exits immediately and never logs anything.

I tried adding a `sleep(1);` but that didn't do the trick.  I searched around but couldn't come up with the right terms.  What's the best way to handle this?

Comment: You cannot call fclose if dbg == NULL.  `dbg = fopen( LOGFILE, "a+" ); if( dbg == NULL ) { perror( LOGFILE ); } else { ...; fclose( dbg ); }`

Comment: have you tried using gdb or another debugger (depending on OS)?

Comment: Ah, thanks William--good catch.  I fixed that little bug, but unfortunately it did not help with my current problem.
Foon - i will try to attach to it.  Normally that is my first choice but this is running as a weird daemon thingy.  Let me see how that goes.

Comment: What happens when data[0] *is* NULL (and we have no idea *what it is* anyway, so we're assuming it is a pointer-to-something) I.e. what is in the code immediately *after* the `if()` expression? Also, why not make *sure* you actually opened the file, put a console-`printf()` at the beginning of your log function, another inside the `if()` block after you think you opened the file, another right before the return. In short, if you actually instrument this you'll probably find the answer to your own question.

Comment: No luck attaching to it with gdb, it just doesn't show anything (i tried both "gdb [name]" and "gdb" "attach [pid]".  
WhozCraig, it's just a pointer to a char.  I'll put some more printf statements in there and see...

Comment: @ChrisC when in doubt, instrument the bejeezors out of your code. More often than not you'll be surprised at the difference between what you *think* is happening and what is *actually* happening.

Comment: all of the sophisticated technology in debuggers - and still the best debugger is `printf("")`. Irony!

Comment: @Aniket grossly unfair, isn't it? Its the one thing people that haven't stepped up to learn gdb, etc. can commonly understand =P

Comment: @WhozCraig a crime punishable by death =P not learning gdb!

Comment: @ChrisC when/if you update that with boatloads of instrumentation, and you still can't figure it out, update the code in the question to include your instrumentation, and *include the output* for us to examine if needed.

Comment: Gah...i put a bunch of printf's in there (even in places that HAVE to hit), then ran the daemon in a separate screen.  All i got was the message "Terminated" (which appears to be an OS message, i don't have that in my code anywhere).  Any other suggestions?  This isn't totally critical to my code but it's frustrating.

Comment: That means your program is crashing. If i had to guess with only this info present it is because `data` cannot be dereferenced (for example, if `data` is a `char**` and has not been properly initialized, or has been deleted and set to NULL, etc.), and doing so faults your process. Remember, though, this is the only code we see. It could be anywhere leading up to this too.

Comment: There is one thing you may also want to change as long as you're in this code. the param to `logoutput()` needs to be a `const char *`, not `char *`. You're passing a literal string, and it is guaranteedly in a read-only segment. And as long as you're instrumenting to stdout, dump that too.

Comment: Sorry for the minimal amounts of code.  This is an implementation of a mix-network and it is one of the individual mixes.  I have it coded so that it has 8 channels.  If a single channel receives data two times (before flushing its buffers off to the next mix and resetting data[*] to NULL), then I'd like to think someone is attempting to inject data into the channel.  Everything works 100% and is behaving as i expect it to, but i'd really love to be able to log a message that says "Hey, something weird just happened so i'm shutting down."  Oh well. :/

Comment: Hah!  It's working now.  I made your correction about the `const char *` and re-re-reviewed all the code, and it is now behaving correctly. I'm not sure exactly what fixed it but i do think the `const char *` was a big part.  Thanks for all your help!!  (I can't mark any of your responses as an answer, so feel free to copy all your text into a reply and i'll flag it as the answer!)

Answer (score 0):

Why not try the following code?

```
#define LOG 1

static int logoutput(char *info) {
    FILE *dbg = NULL;
    dbg = fopen(LOGFILE, "a+");
    if(dbg != NULL) {
        fprintf(dbg, "Blah%d: %s\n", PARTNUM, info);
        fclose(dbg);
    }
    else {
        printf("Error writing to log file.\n");
    }
    return 0;//all good!
}    

static void logoutput_exit(char *info) {
   while(logoutput(info) != 0);
   exit(1);
}

if (data[0] != NULL) {
    if(LOG) logoutput_exit("WARNING, something bad happened on port 1!");
    //Adding a sleep(1); before this didn't help.
}
```

Comment: how does `logoutput()` *not* break that `while()` loop on the first execution, regardless of success or failure? (I.e. how does it return anything besides 0) ? Also, how will `fclose()` behave when the `fopen()` fails?

Comment: @WhozCraig the idea is to add a delay.. which is what the OP wants. If I have not clearly misread the question(the `sleep(1)` part)

Comment: Methinks the delay was under some misappropriate premise that somehow stalling before the exit(1) will allow the file to flush, which won't make a difference if the call to open, write, and close it are successful. And as written, this will delay no longer than the OP's original code. `logoutput()` always returns 0, so the while condition is gone. the only delay is invoking one extra call-stack-frame.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, the `sleep()` was just an attempt to let the buffers flush out but it didn't work.  I did try throwing in a separate function for a call to `exit()`, but my code still exits before anything can be written out.